# Add JavaScript in OpenWRT LuCI interface?

Tags: openwrt, luci

I would like to add a javascript in the [gluon webinterface](https://github.com/freifunk-gluon/packages/blob/master/gluon/gluon-config-mode-contact-info/files/lib/gluon/config-mode/wizard/0500-contact-info.lua) so if you enter a pair of coordinates into the latitude input field, the logitute part is automatically moved to the other input field.

The [LuCI documentation](http://luci.subsignal.org/trac/wiki/Documentation/CBI) doesn't shw such options.

How can I add such a javascript in the luci interface?

Comment: Also asked here: https://github.com/elationfoundation/luci_tutorials/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added the javascript in the view at the end here:

https://github.com/rubo77/packages/blob/coordinates/gluon/gluon-config-mode/files/usr/lib/lua/luci/view/gluon-config-mode/cbi/wizard.htm

Which is quite a hack, better create a package, seee:

https://github.com/freifunk-gluon/packages/pull/47